# Parse a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary looks like this:

```
 data = {
    start = {
        name = "abc";
        age = "123";
        id = AA838DDE;
    };
};
```

how can I parser the dictionary to get individual name, age, and id?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *name = dictionary[@"data"][@"start"][@"name"];
```

Comment: Use @"data", not "data", etc.

Comment: Thank you :) I forgot the @

Comment: It didn't work.  dictionary[@"data"][@"start"] return an array.

Comment: You forgot the last part: @["name"]

Comment: Oh sorry, if it is an array then u can get the index [0] or [1] etc.

Comment: Btw, you are doing no research buddy!

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if it pleases you :) @user2543991

Answer (score 0):

I add an other answer because I hate the new Objective-C syntax (sorry @Raphael Olivieira)

```
NSString *name = [[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"start"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@", name);
```

Longer than the previous answer but you know what you do and you don't code in C.

BTW, using the other syntax :

```
NSString *name = dictionary[@"data"][@"start"][0][@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@", name);
```

Comment: No problems with style preference but just to clarify, this is not C, this is part of the objective-c literals http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: yes of course I said it's the new syntax but, it seems to the C syntax

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply try:

```
int arrCount = [[[dictionaryObject valueForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"start"] count];

for(int i = 0 ; i < arrCount ; i++)
{
    NSString *strName = [[[[dictionaryObject objectForKey:@"data"]
                                             objectForKey:@"start"]
                                            objectAtIndex:i]
                                             objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString *strAge = [[[[dictionaryObject objectForKey:@"data"]
                                            objectForKey:@"start"]
                                           objectAtIndex:i]
                                            objectForKey:@"age"];

    NSString *strID = [[[[dictionaryObject objectForKey:@"data"]
                                           objectForKey:@"start"]
                                          objectAtIndex:i]
                                           objectForKey:@"id"];

    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@", strName, strAge, strID);
}
```